# Android Cursor can't find mp3 file after I rename it

Tags: android, kotlin, rename, mp3, audio-player

I am working on Mp3 player. I am using curosr for that. My problem is that after I rename a pm3 file, cursor is unable to find that mp3 file. I looked to my folder where mp3 file is placed and it is renamed.  Do you have any idea? I am getting music with a cursor:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private fun getAllAudio(): ArrayList<Music> {
    val tempAudioList = ArrayList<Music>()
    val selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0"
    val uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    Log.d("SONGS", uri.path!!)
    val projection = arrayOf(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID
    )
    val cursor = this.contentResolver.query(
        uri,
        projection,
        selection,
        null,
        null
    )
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val path = cursor.getString(0)
            val title = cursor.getString(1)
            val artist = cursor.getString(2)
            val album = cursor.getString(3)
            val duration = cursor.getString(4)
            val size = cursor.getString(5)
            val id = cursor.getString(6)
            val art = getAlbumArt(path)

            val file = File(path)
            Log.d("ALLSONGS", path)

            if (file.exists()) {

                val musicFiles = Music(path, title, artist, album, duration, size, id, art)
                tempAudioList.add(musicFiles)
            }
        }
        cursor.close()
    }
    return tempAudioList
}
```

I am asking for permissions:

```
 private fun askStoragePermissions() {
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
        .withPermissions(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
        .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
            override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
                if (report!!.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                    Log.d("MAIN_ACTIVITY", "Permission granted")
                    musicList = getAllAudio()
                }

                if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied) {

                }
            }

            override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                permissions: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
                token: PermissionToken?
            ) {
                token!!.continuePermissionRequest()
            }
        })
        .onSameThread()
        .check()
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Renaming file:

```
val newName = mView.edit_txt_new_title.text.toString()
        val path = ArrayList(music.path.split('/'))
        path[path.size - 1] = newName
        var newPath = ""
        for (i in 0 until path.size - 1) {
            newPath += "${path[i]}/"
        }

        newPath += "$newName.mp3"

        val file = File(music.path)
        if (file.renameTo(File(newPath)))
            if (File(newPath).renameTo(File(newPath)))
            Toast.makeText(context, "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        Log.d("RENAME", "$newPath -- ${music.path}")
```

Comment: If you renamed it to pm3 as you said above, that might do it. :)  Having said that, details are missing.  You open the file and start playing it and then rename it and it cannot be found?  Or what is the exact scenario?  I for one am having trouble determining the sequence of events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After renaming the file you have to update the MediaStore to do this use the below method when your file is renamed successfully :

```
  private fun updateMediaStore(music_Id: String, newPath: String, newName: String) {
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, newPath)
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, newName)
        val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, music_Id.toLong())
        contentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null)
    }
```

In the method above I updated the path and the dispaly name, you can used here :

```
/*
rest of your code
*/

 val file = File(music.path)
 if (file.renameTo(File(newPath)))
     if (File(newPath).renameTo(File(newPath))) {
         Log.d("RENAME", "$newPath -- ${music.path}")
         Toast.makeText(context, "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
         updateMediaStore(music.id,newPath,newName)
    }
```

Comment: OMG! I am so grateful. I would never figure it by myself. :D

Comment: if you noticed in your code it displays the whole list but before adding it to the list you check if the file exists so without updating the media store you always check the old version

Comment: one thing when you create a new file remember to add the file extension is not always "mp3" you can do that with MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE

Comment: Yes, I was trying to delete file but it did not delete it properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66229075/file-is-not-removed-properly-in-android

Comment: But thanks to you I know that I need to update MediaStore after deleting file.

Comment: yous you need to Updated  it

Comment: please check this answer here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/20719091/7085389